# Setting numerical key values in a hash

Tags: hash

I now know the answer to this but I’m posting it here as a note to myself and in case it helps people.

Let's say you are looping through some entries and storing values in a hash…

```
{% set myHash = {} %}

{% for entry in entries %}
    {% set value  = entry.intro %}
    {% set myHash = myHash|merge({
        (entry.id) : { intro : value }
    }) %}
{% endfor %}
```

The `entry.id` is a variable so it needs to be wrapped in brackets as a *dynamic* key.

But when you `{{ dump(myHash) }}` it turns out the numeric keys have just become index numbers – `[0]` in the truncated example below…

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["intro"]=>
    string(13) "My intro text"
…
```

But there is a straightforward [answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/37603/3507)…

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to prepend a letter to the numerical key…

```
{% for entry in entries %}
    {% set eId   = "e#{entry.id}" %} {# interpolation* #}
    {% set value = entry.intro %}

    {% set myHash = myHash|merge({
        (eId) : { intro : value }
    }) %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now the hash stores the custom key as a string…

```
array(10) {
  ["e1234"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["intro"]=>
    string(13) "My intro text"
…
```

…which you can clean up as needed…

```
{% for key, properties in hash %}
    {% set key = key|replace('e', '') %}
    …
{% endfor %}
```

…or factor into lookups…

```
{% set testId    = 'e1234' %}
{% set testIntro = myHash[testId].intro %}
{# `testIntro`  == 'My intro text' #}
```

Apparently, it's [a PHP thing](https://twitter.com/CraftCMS/status/1384518340870344705?s=20).

*[Interpolation is often preferable to concatenation](https://servd.host/blog/10-things-to-not-do-in-your-craft-cms-twig-templates) <-- see item #4.